# How to use an assembly deployed unto a custom bin folder?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, probing

```
MainApp/bin
```

There are some custom dlls here:

```
MainApp/bin/Custom_Dlls
```

I've added a probing as below to the web.config file located under the MainApp:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <probing privatePath="bin;bin\Custom_Dlls" />
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

When I run my .aspx web page whose dll is under Custom_Dlls folder, it shows me an error message that the "Could not load type ..." which means it can't find the dll.

```
System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): Could not load type <AssemblyName>.WebForm1'.
```

I've also tried using the full physical path "file:///C:\MainApp\bin\Custom_Dlls" but doesn't work.

Any help? anything else I'd need to do?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can sign your assembly and deploy it to GAC. This will do the job for you.
Alternative is to load assembly at runtime. Take a look at my post for loading plugins:
[VB.NET dynamic plugin components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055308/vb-net-dynamic-plugin-components/12058493#12058493)